# why is this degree sequence not possible?

Tags: graph-theory

True or false? It is not possible for a graph to have degree sequence 6,5,4,3,2. The answer key says its true but I thought it is possible because the number of odd numbers is even. Addmitedly I wasn't able to draw such a graph but that doesn't prove much. Why is true the answer?

Comment: If a vertex has degree $6$, shouldn't at least $6$ other vertices have a positive degree?

Comment: Not in a multi-graph @JonathanY.

Comment: If you're allowing multigraphs then there's a counterexample that's not too hard to find - start with two vertices joined by 4 edges.

Comment: This is an intro course and I haven't heard of multigraphs.

Comment: @Celeritas Intro courses can touch on multigraphs too, but point taken. The basic gist of what Jonathan said is that unless you allow two vertices to share more than one edge, you can't have a vertex of degree 6 in a graph that has only 5 vertices.

Comment: Thanks. I struggle a lot with math,  what does it mean I couldn't see this? What exercises or knowledge should I work on to answer these types of questions?

Comment: Celeritas, I don't think it necessarily means anything, and you shouldn't get discouraged. I do think, however, that the internet did you a disservice in this case. A guideline I like (and tell my students about) is this: if you haven't yet kicked a question around for 4 days (actively thinking about it for 15 minutes a day is fine, because the brain keeps working on its own) it's way too soon to give up or seek outside assistance. Here, for example, if you'd tried to doodle a graph like this, the points Eric and I made would've become apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph given has only five vertices. So if you do not allow multiple edges between the same two vertices, then it is impossible for any vertex to have six neighbors. A slightly more subtle point: it is also impossible for any vertex to have five neighbors if vertices cannot be connected to themselves.